# WeForm texbox control. action related to ontextchanged event not happening

Tags: asp.net, system.web.ui.webcontrols

Web.UI.Controls.TextBox

in my aspx page i have used-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="tmaintextchanged"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

in my code behind :

```
<asp:Label ID="show" runat="server" ></asp:Label >

protected void tmaintextchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            show.Text = "working";
        }
```

when I am executing this ,Why is the text of label "show" not changing.Kindly help. Am i missing any configuration to the Text box.

Comment: Are you using any update panels? Did you put a breakpoint in the tmaintextchanged method to make sure it's being called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set autopostback on TextBox control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="tmaintextchanged"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

**Update**

see this post:

[How do I make a Textbox Postback on KeyUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758240/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-postback-on-keyup)

Comment: thank you it works now , but the function is called only after the textbox control loses focus and not on text change. Can you please help with this ?

Comment: You will have to use a different approach