# asp.net textbox - update label onkeyup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm generating some labels, textboxes and so on from my codebehind, and i need to update a label when a key is pressed in the textbox, i've been looking at this: [How do I make a Textbox Postback on KeyUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758240/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-postback-on-keyup) 
And tried to convert it to be dynamic - but i can't get this to work.

This is in my asp.net/html code:

the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshUpdatePanel(id) {
        __doPostBack(id, '');
    };
</script>
```

the body:

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        <asp:Panel ID="testpanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlProdKits" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
```

and my codebehind:

```
TextBox txtQuantity = new TextBox() { Width = 30, Text = "0", MaxLength = 4, ID = prod.Number };
txtQuantity.Style["text-align"] = "right";
txtQuantity.TextChanged += delegate(object o, EventArgs e) { lblPriceTotal.Text = "new text!"; };
                txtQuantity.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", string.Format("RefreshUpdatePanel(ContentPlaceHolder1_{0});", txtQuantity.ClientID));

AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = txtQuantity.ClientID;
update.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

and then i add the textbox to the first panel:

```
testpanel.Controls.Add(txtQuantity);
```

the label is added to the panel inside the update panel:

```
pnlProdKits.Controls.Add(priceTotal);
```

Comment: Can't you use `javascript` or `J-Query`?

Comment: well it should be possible if i knew how to do it.. :-)

Comment: If you want postback on `TextBox` can you try this code, `txtQuantity.AutoPostBack = true;`

Comment: that only works when i press enter or tab..

Comment: `i need to update a label when a key is pressed in the textbox`   .You want to update `Label` with `TextBox` value?

Comment: nop, i use the label to show a total price based on the textbox - so well kinda.. but not fully

Answer (score 0):

As discussed,

You can try the following script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function RefreshUpdatePanel(){
//Find all textboxes which you want to get the values by their `ClientID` property. Like,
var a = $('#' + '<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>').val();
var b = $('#' + '<%= txtQuantity2.ClientID %>').val();

//Since the value will be in string, you need to convert it to numeric for mathematical operations

var sum = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);

//Then find the label and assign the result

$('#'+'<%= Label1.ClientID %>').val(sum.toFixed(2));

}

</script>
```

Rest of the code for adding `onkeyup/onkeydown` will be same.

You can try just adding `alert(1);` in the `function` to check if it hits it or not.