# Typing events changes from asp textbox to web browser control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb6, webbrowser-control

We have a requirement where we load our aspx website in Web browser control using VB6. In the asp page there is a textbox where user types the query for support. So it is just a text content. Now we want to handle the events when user types in textbox. Typing event(i saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758240/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-postback-on-keyup) but it does not send events to web browser control) or change event of web page textbox should be communicated to web browser control. How it can be implemented?