# Why controls don't behave on postback as expected?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, postback

Please forgive me if this has been asked before or if I am not asking correctly.  I am new to programming and working on a school assignment.

Assignment: Create a web application project with 2 textboxes and a button control
a) On changing the text in field one the text in field 2 should blank.
b) On pressing the button the text from field one should be put in field 2
c) All event should be handled on the server side, so no javascript.  (Confirmed this with teacher, NO JAVASCRIPT)

Here is the problem:

**The page loads with both blank text boxes.  I enter text in textbox1, press ok, page reloads but there is nothing in textbox2 (its supposed to copy contents of textbox1).  If I press the submit button again, the text copies to textbox 2 as it should.**

If I change the text in textbox1, leave focus, page reloads and blanks box 2 as it should.  If I press submit button, it copies the text as it should.

I simply cannot get it to work properly the first time the page is loaded.

Here is the code for default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 141px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And here is the code from default.aspx.vb:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text

    End Sub

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox2.Text = ""

    End Sub


End Class
```

---

I know that when I am entering text into textbox1 for the first time that it is triggering the event for textchanged, but it seems to be happening in the wrong order that I need.

What am I not doing right?

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Ask your instructor what he means by "no JavaScript". Does he mean that _you_ can't write any JavaScript, or that ASP.NET cannot write any JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is incorrect to say "NO JS" because `Postback` is JS-invoked event. With no JS at all it is not possible because you can't cause `Postback` by typing into textbox. And `TextChange` event happens on postback when Asp.Net determined that content of TB has changed.
So if you want to type with postback you need minimal JS as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758240/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-postback-on-keyup)

You need to remove `AutoPostBack` from your `TextBox1` because it causes postback when focus moves from textbox. This is the problem. Your button is never pressed on the first pass hence your `TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text` never runs on the first time. Second time you already pressing the button, therefore code works.