# Textbox search with dropdown results

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls

I (think I) want to develop a custom control for my program in VB .net where I type into a textbox and simple search results will then be displayed underneath it (from a predefined set of items). Like auto suggest in google search.

I believe the combobox does something similar to this but I think it only works on prefixes.

At the moment I have a separate search form from which I use to filter a lot of possibilities and then use drag-and-drop to get the desired item into a TextBox.

So ideally I want to combine this with a TextBox into which one can start typing at which point some results will be displayed and a user can select the item they want. (Say, an item from a list of products)

Is this a good idea?
How can I go about it best?
Does it already exist?

It has been bugging me for AGES!

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is supported out of the box in Windows Forms 2.0 and beyond.  Check out the [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) and [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx) properties of both the TextBox and ComboBox windows forms objects.

Comment: This doesn't allow for more advanced searches, this is just prefixes.

I want to combine the advanced features of a search form with the TextBox.

Comment: You might have to override the AutoComplete abilities using something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515561/how-can-i-dynamically-change-auto-complete-entries-in-a-c-combobox-or-textbox.  At which point, you're almost back to your original idea of wrapping it all up in a custom control.  The OOTB auto complete capabilities should lighten the load a bit, though.