# ComboBox AutoComplete with Key/Value Pair

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox with the following code:

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var service = WebServiceHelper.GetCoreService())
    {
        string physicianXml = service.SearchPhysicians(SessionInfo.Current.ClientCode, SessionInfo.Current.MachineName,
                                    SessionInfo.Current.Username, comboBox1.Text);

        var physicians = PhysicianItemList.FromXml(physicianXml);

        AutoCompleteStringCollection autoCompleteStringCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        foreach (var physician in physicians.Items)
        {
            autoCompleteStringCollection.Add(physician.LastName + ", " + physician.FirstName);
        }

        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteStringCollection;
        comboBox1.Select(comboBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

Basically, a user types the first few characters of a physician's name and it should populate the auto-complete list with the top 100 matching records.  It works great, but I need to associate it back to a key (either the PK from the table, or the Physician's NPI number).  It seems the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` doesn't support keys.  Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?  There are approximately 7 million records in the table, so I don't want to prepopulate the ComboBox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, build a `Dictionary<String, int>` for the name, id pairs as well. Then use some event (textbox validation or user submit/save click) to lookup and set the id. You could store the dictionary on the textbox `Tag`.

**Edit**

For some reason I thought you were working with a textbox control. Forget about the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` and just build a `Dictionary<String, int>`. For the combobox set your autocompletesource to ListItems, set the combobox display name and value and set the datasource to the dictionary.

```
combobox.DisplayMember = "key";
combobox.ValueMember = "value";
combobox.AutocompleteSource = AutocompleteSource.ListItems;
combobox.DataSource = myDictionary;
```

However you should only populate the datasource and autocomplete once when the user enters n characters in the combobox, otherwise it gets buggy. I tried to use this for a dynamic autocomplete once (eg the list clears if the user clear the text and retypes), but I had to forget about the combobox and use a hybrid textbox listbox approach much like this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/515561/1914530)

Comment: If I follow you, you're saying have two collections: one Dictionary, and one AutoCompleteStringCollection?  How do I match the two to lookup the ID?  There could be duplicate physician names (like "John Smith").  Although, now that I think about it - that could cause another problem since the user will never know which to pick.  Hmmm

Comment: That's right. Yes, needs to be unique strings. Both for the dictionary and for your user's sake in identifying the correct physician.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that AutoCompleteStringComplete was made specifically for strings (hence, the name).

You may want to look into the parents (`IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`) and see if you can homebrew something templated toward a key/value struct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` and when I set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` I get errors saying it can't be casted.  If I try to explicitly cast it, it throws an exception at runtime.  I think I might just have to add the Physician's NPI number to the string, so it could show as "Doh, John (#11111)" and regex parse the number. Sucky. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Glad it helped! Having to parse the strings isn't the worst thing that could happen. You may even be able to use `String.Split()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Too late but maybe someone will use this code :

```
this.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;

RNProveedor rnProveedor = new RNProveedor();
var listaProveedores = rnProveedor.Buscar();
Dictionary<int, String> dicTemp = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var entidad in listaProveedores)
{
    dicTemp.Add(entidad.ProvNro, entidad.ProNombre);
}

this.DataSource = new BindingSource(dicTemp, null);
this.DisplayMember = "Value";
this.ValueMember = "Key";
```

And to select the value

```
public int GetValorDecimal()
{
    KeyValuePair<int, string> objeto = (KeyValuePair<int, string>)this.SelectedItem;     
    return objeto.Key;
}
```

With this example you won't have any problem with duplicated strings as the examples above